# What causes Spotify App to restart unexpectedly?

Tags: spotify

I've been working on a Spotify app and it's been going well; just recently, however, there is a code path that, when I execute it, causes the Spotify app to act as if it has been reloaded. The console is cleared, all local state is gone, etc.  I can't seem to track down what is causing it to get refreshed. Are there known errors that, when triggered, cause a refresh?

Thanks.

-dave

Comment: Please post the code that is causing the problem, along with any related code. Otherwise we won't be able to take a look and offer any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the problem was that I was not returning False after my form's onChange method was called; this caused a form submit & page reload.